# Is it possible to tell that the "currying" is an action reverse of the "partial application"?

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell through reading the *"Learn You a Haskell for Great Goog!"* book. I want to be sure I correctly understand that is "currying".

I understand a function can't get more then one parameter. When a function has more then one parameter it *actually* works as a function with one parameter. I.e. this:

```
func :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

works like this (and is the same):

```
func :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))
```

I.e. a function returns a function, that returns a function too, etc. This "nested doll" behaviour is called a "currying" (curried function). First variant of code is like a "syntax sugar".

Any function with more than zero parameter can be *partially applied*. I.e. it is possible to tell that *the "currying" is an action reverse of the "partial application"*. Am I right?

Comment: *Currying* is a *way* to express a *n*-ary function with *n* unary function and is one of the easiest way to achieve *partial application* (but not a sole one).

Comment: I think your main problem is perhaps due to the fact that there's no such thing as "partial application" in Haskell.  There is just application.  If we "say" (to help us understand) that `f :: Int -> Int -> Int` has two arguments (which is not technically correct) then we can also "say" (again to help us understand) that `f 5` is "partially applied" (which again is not technically correct).  These are both analogies to aid understanding but neither has any technical meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I.e. it is possible to tell that the "currying" is an action reverse of the "partial application".

Almost but the other way around: "Currying" can be seen as the **same thing** as "partial application".

Let me explain with the help of a ghci session. We start by defining some type synonyms for different kinds of functions.

```
Prelude> type Binary a b c = (a, b) -> c
Prelude> type Curried a b c = a -> (b -> c)
Prelude> type Unary a b = a -> b
```

Here, we have two ways to represent a binary function: We have `Binary` functions like in mathematics, that is, functions that accept a tuple. Then we have `Curried` functions like usually in Haskell, that is, functions that return a function. And for completeness, we also have a special name for `Unary` functions.

Now we can use the standard `curry` and `uncurry` functions to convert between the two representations of binary functions. In ghci, we can check this as follows:

```
Prelude> :t curry :: Binary a b c -> Curried a b c
curry :: Binary a b c -> Curried a b c
  :: Binary a b c -> Curried a b c

Prelude> :t uncurry :: Curried a b c -> Binary a b c
uncurry :: Curried a b c -> Binary a b c
  :: Curried a b c -> Binary a b c
```

(Note that when you type `:t foo :: SomeType`, then ghci will check whether `foo` has type `SomeType`. If yes, ghci will print it again. If not, ghci will complain).

So as Bartek correctly states in his answer, the inverse of `curry` is `uncurry`. But we can also understand the type of `curry` as follows:

```
Prelude> :t curry :: Binary a b c -> a -> Unary b c
curry :: Binary a b c -> a -> Unary b c
  :: Binary a b c -> a -> Unary b c
```

If we write the type like this, we see that we can use `curry` to partially apply a `Binary` function: Given a `f :: Binary a b c` and the first argument `x :: a` we can use `curry f x` to yield a `Unary b c` that is still waiting for the second argument of type `b`.

Comment: Thank you! Can I say the "currying" is a synonym of "partial application" in Haskell?

Comment: @Bush of course it's not. It doesn't apply anything. Note "we can use `curry f x`" in the answer above.

Comment: >of course it's not. But what about this: >*"Currying" can be seen as the same thing as "partial application"*?

Comment: If you do `curry f`, you do currying, but not partial application, so the two are not always the same. Now if you do `curry f x` you do both currying and partial application, so the two can be seen as the same thing from some points of view

Answer (score 7):

### No.

A reverse of currying is *uncurrying*.

```
f :: a -> b -> c

f' :: (a, b) -> c
f' = -- uncurried f

f'' :: a -> b -> c
f'' = -- curried f' = f
```

A curried function, despite having its "language" arity reduced to 1, keeps the "semantic" arity unchanged (becuse you still have to provide every value for the tuple). The only thing that changes in comparison is the way you pass the arguments.

Partial application is an application that reduces the arity of the function to a number bigger than 0. This is an *irreversible* operation; you can't *unapply* arguments.

```
--   1    2
f :: a -> b -> c

--    1
f' :: b -> c
f' = f c -- partially applied f

--     0 arguments
f'' :: c
f'' = f c1 c2 -- fully applied f
```

Comment: I understand what is `partial application`. But the `currying` notion is not clear to me still...

Comment: @Bush the question was "*is currying reverse of partial application*", to which the answer is *no*.

Comment: why your `f'` signature is not the `f' :: a -> (a -> a)`? For your case first parameter is a function...

Comment: it should be `f' :: (a, a) -> a`. yet's it better to use distinct type variables `a, b, c`: `f :: a -> b -> c` and `f' :: (a, b) -> c`. Also `f'` is actually *uncurried*, as in `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`. I have troubles to remember which way is which myself too.

Comment: @Bush oops, I got the "un" part wrong in the first example. Result of curry-by default in Haskell, no less.

Comment: @phadej you're right, I'll change to distinct type variables. Heh, confusing matters even more, but hopefully the answer will be ok in the end